# flock disappearing after parent die

Tags: python, linux

I take flock then fork, and expect that "lock" would be unlocked
only when child and parent died.
But after parent process finished,
assert triggered:

```
test.lck NOT found in lslocks output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "daemon_and_flock.py", line 25, in <module>
    assert check_lock(path)
AssertionError
```

Any idea how to fix this, and force lock to stay alive until all related file descriptors were closed in both child and parent proceces?

```
import fcntl, sys, os, subprocess, time

def check_lock(path: str) -> bool:
    lines = subprocess.check_output(["lslocks"]).decode('utf-8')
    for line in lines.split('\n'):
        if path in line:
            print(f"{path} found in lslocks output")
            return True
    print(f"{path} NOT found in lslocks output")
    return False
        
path = sys.argv[1]
fh = open(path, "a")
fcntl.flock(fh, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
assert check_lock(path)
print(f"before fork: file handle {fh.fileno()}")

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    print(f"child: file handle {fh.fileno()}")
    assert check_lock(path)
    time.sleep(1)
    assert check_lock(path)
else:
    print(f"parent: file handle {fh.fileno()}")
    assert check_lock(path)
```

Comment: LOCK_EX is exclusive to one process.

Comment: @stark Manual page doesn't specify anything about LOCK_EX vs LOCK_SH: Locks created by flock() are associated with an open file description (see open(2)).  This means that duplicate file descriptors (created by, for  example,  fork(2)
or  dup(2))  refer  to the same lock, and this lock may be modified or released using any of these file descriptors.  Furthermore, the lock is released either by an
explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these duplicate file descriptors, or when all such file descriptors have been closed.

Comment: `lslocks` won't give the correct information in the second invocation of `check_lock` in the child, as the parent process has terminated, and `lslocks` appears to not consider non-existent processes. Check the contents of `/proc/locks`, looking for the parent PID instead. In my testing, the lock sticks around until both parent and child have terminated ✌